# Validation not working on register.php and posts to verify.php MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation, post

The problem I am getting is that I have 2 forms. student_register.php and student_verify.php So when a user fills in the register form and submits , the form posts to student_verify.php but ignores all the php script on student_register.php. It ignores all validation constraints i put down. Look below (It does connect to MySQL)

I have a form called student_register.php This includes this following code:

```
<?php 
include_once("scripts/global2.php");
mysql_connect("mysql.cms.gre.ac.uk","****","****") or die("Could not connect     to server");
mysql_select_db("mdb_mj046") or die("Could not select database");
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$addline1 = $_POST['addline1'];
$addline2 = $_POST['addline2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
$college_id = $_POST['college_id'];


//error handeling
    //If all the fields have been inserted
    if ( (!$username) || (!$fname) || (!$lname) || (!$dob) || (!$gender) || (!$addline1) || (!$addline2) || (!$city) || (!$postcode) ||(!$phone) || (!$mobile) || (!$email) || (!$pass1) || (!$pass2) || (!$college_id) ) {
    $message = 'Please insert all fields in the form below!';
}else{
    //Checking if the password matches
    if($pass1 != $pass2){
        $message = 'Your password fields do not match!';    
    }else{


        //securing the data, if passwords do match
        $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);  
        $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);    
        $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
        $dob = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$dob);
        $gender = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$gender);
        $addline1 = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$addline1);
        $addline2 = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$addline2);
        $city = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$city);
        $postcode = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$postcode);  
        $phone = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$phone);
        $mobile = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$mobile);


        //Encrypts the password
        $pass1 = sha1($pass1);
        //Gets rid of any unwanted characters
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

        //Check for Dublicates-USERNAME
        $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM students WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1") or die ("Could not check username");  
        $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

        //Check for Dublicates-EMAIL
        $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM students WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1") or die ("Could not check username");  
        $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

        if($count_username > 0){
            $message = 'Your username is already in use';   
        }else if($count_email > 0){
            $message = 'Your email is already in use!'; 
        }else{
            ///Insert the members into the DB


            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO students (username, fname, lname, dob, gender, addline1, addline2, city, postcode, phone, mobile, email, password, activationKey, active, college_id) VALUES ('$username','$fname', '$lname','$dob', '$gender', '$addline1','$addline2', '$city','$postcode','$phone','$mobile', '$email','$password', '$activationKey', '','$college_id' )") or die ("Could not insert your information");


            $student_id = mysql_insert_id();

            $message = 'You have now been registered!';
//insert the members

            }

    }       

}   

}


 ?>


         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register to my website</title>
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container center">
   <h1>Register to my site by filling the fields below!</h1>
  <h3>Student Need to Register!</h3>
    <p><?php print("$message");?></p>
    <form action="student_verify.php" method="post" >
      <table width="318" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Username:</td>
          <td width="144"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"  />       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>First Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date of Birth:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="addline1" placeholder="Address Line 1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="addline2" placeholder="Address Line 2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Postcode:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Phone Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>College ID: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="college_id" placeholder="College ID"  /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"/>
        <br />        
        <input type="submit" value="Register!" /> <br/>
        <a href="index.php">Go Back  </a> 
      </p>    
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that , all the PHP code in student_register.php does not run, it does not check for errors or nothing, it simply just posts to student_verify.php, meaning that the code inserted does not run. This is what my student_verify.php looks like:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
session_start();
mysql_connect("mysql.cms.gre.ac.uk","****","*****") or die("Could not connect to server");
mysql_select_db("mdb_mj046") or die("Could not select database");
$note='';
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) { 
##User is registering, insert data until we can activate it

$activationKey =  rand(12345,98765);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$addline1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addline1']);
$addline2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addline2']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = sha1($_POST['pass1']);
$college_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['college_id']);


$sql="INSERT INTO students (username, fname, lname, dob, gender, addline1, addline2, city, postcode, phone, mobile, email, password, activationKey, active, college_id) VALUES ('$username','$fname', '$lname','$dob', '$gender', '$addline1','$addline2', '$city','$postcode','$phone','$mobile', '$email','$password', '$activationKey', '','$college_id' )";



if (!mysql_query($sql))

  {

  die('Error:ERROR !! ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo 
    $note="An email has been sent to" .$_POST[email]. "with an activation key. Our systems are going to verify that you are a member of your institue. Please check your mail to complete registration.";

##Send activation Email

$to      = $_POST[email];
$subject = " E-Attendance Tracking & Monitoring System";


$message = "Welcome to our website!\r\rYou, or someone using your email address, has completed registration at Greenwich Freecycle. You can complete registration by clicking the following link:\rhttp:stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~mj046/membership2/verify.php?$activationKey\r\rIf this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our mailing list.\r\rRegards,\ Greenwich Freecycle Team";

$headers = 'From: noreply@ RBGFreecycle.com' . "\r\n" .

    'Reply-To: noreply@ mj046@greenwich.ac.uk' . "\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    ini_set("sendmail_from","mj046@greenwich.ac.uk");

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

} else {

##User isn't registering, check verify code and change activation code to null, status to activated on success

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM students"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($queryString == $row["activationKey"]){

       echo $note="Congratulations!" . $row["username"] . " is now the proud new owner of an Greennwich Freecycle Website.com account.Please click here to access your account Profile Page ";

       $sql="UPDATE students SET activationKey = '', active='1' WHERE (student_id = $row[student_id])";

       if (!mysql_query($sql))

  {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

    }

  }

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Verification Page</title>
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="container center" >
    <h3> Verification Page</h3>
    <form action="verify.php" method="POST">
    <p><?php print("$note");?></p>
    <a href="student_login.php">Login</a>
    </form>
            </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I dont understand why it fails to validate the data on student_register.php, Could anyone help me please , kind regards

Comment: Sorry, I'm not scrolling through all your code. Please update with only relevant parts. Also, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: From the looks of it you first need to post to `student_register.php` and then include `student_verify.php`. @AarolamaBluenk `mysql_` isn't deprecated yet, but will be in PHP5.5.

Comment: because your form posts directly to student_verify.php. The post **NEVER** touches student_register.php

Comment: @MarcB so how do i make it go through the php code at student_register.php before successfully posting it to student_verify.php

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk PHP5.5 isn't out of alpha yet.

Comment: @jordan: mysql_*() is deprecated NOW. as in "don't use it". It'll most likely be REMOVED in PHP 5.5, but you shouldn't be using the function complex at all as of last year. Deprecated = "don't use, it's obsolete/unwanted".

Comment: Thanks @MarcB Stuff like this confuses people new to php

Comment: @MarcB I know that people shouldn't use it, it is insecure and is slow. I agree that PDO or MySQLi should be used. Quoted from the php.net link: `deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future`. I am expecting OP is thinking of running this on a production server, which shouldn't be running PHP 5.5 right now. All my development servers are on PHP5.5. Upvoted your comment anyway, just to inform other people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the post request to `student_register.php` first, and then include `student_verify.php`. Your post request is never sent to `student_register.php`.

You can change this by changing the `action` of your form to `student_register.php` and then insert `include 'student_verify.php';` where suitable.

Comment: yeh i changed the action on the form to student_register.php but if i include: include 'student_verify.php'; anywhere on student_register.php it shows student_verify.php page on student_register.php

Comment: Is this not the expected behaviour of your script? What _is_ the expected behaviour?

Comment: the expected behaviour is to run all the validation on student_register.php and then post to student_verify.php where it then tells the user that an activation email has been sent, enforcing them to check their email and activate their account

Comment: You should include `student_verify.php` after `$message = 'You have now been registered!';`

Answer (score 0):

try to make your input like that

```
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!" />
```

and instead of

```
   if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
```

replace it by

```
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```